# Need array to contain all 12 keys for the 12 months in loop even if month is not found

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, mysqli

I understand `basic arrays` but when they get more advanced I get a little lost. Can someone help me with the following code and `array`?

I am storing my `DB query` into an `array`. If all 12 months are not in the DB then that is all that is stored (as it should). However, my problem is that I need the `array` to have all 12 `keys` so I can print this out.

```
// Example amounts

0, 0, 0, 0, 5.23, 0, 0, 158.35, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

Basically if it does not exist I should still be able to print out zero for that month.

Here is my code:

```
$closedsales = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT MONTH(date) as month, sum(amount) as total FROM sales WHERE user_id = '".$userid."' AND status = 'S' GROUP BY MONTH(date)");

    while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($closedsales) ) {
    $monthlysales[$row['month']] = $row['total'];
    }

       foreach($monthlysales as $key => $amount) {
         echo "$amount <br />";
       }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prefill your result array:

```
$monthlysales = array_fill_keys(range(1, 12), 0);
```

Then run your loop, which will replace the elements with the rows from the table. If a row is missing from the table, it will have the initial 0 value.

Comment: ^ easier solution for your exact case here.

Comment: Very nice, thanks! I will remember that function!! Thanks again for always being helpful!!

Answer (score 1):

```
$allmonthlysales = array_fill_keys(range(1, 12), 0);
foreach($monthlysales as $month => $sales){
    $allmonthlysales[$month] = $sales;
}
var_dump($allmonthlysales);
```

- Prepare and `array` with keys `1-12` and `0` as `value` meaning months with no sales.
- Merge the `array` with months that have sales with the empty one built above.
- And you got what you need...

Comment: When arrays have numeric keys, `array_merge` concatenates them, it doesn't merge the similar keys.